# Pulling a String array from processing.js to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, processing.js

I am trying to send a upload to my database some data that I gather from a game in processing.js and a form. The data is sent to the database once the submit button on the form is pressed.
My issue is that I am not able to pull the String array from my processing.js and send it to the database.

The name of the array in the processing.js is answerArray.

my html:

```
<form action="submitted.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return js_sendData()">
    <input name="email" placeholder="Mail" type="text" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" class="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="I solved it!" class="button">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function js_sendData() {
            $.post( "save.php", {'answer[]': answerArray}, function( data ) {
            $( "#status" ).html( data );});
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

my php (submitted.php):

// Connect to the database

```
$con=mysqli_connect(connection details*);

 //Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Answer (Name, Mail)
VALUES ('$name', '$email')");
```

the save php that doesnt work (save.php):

```
        // Connect to the database
$con=mysqli_connect(connection details*);

 //Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$dta = $_POST['answer'];

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Answer 
    SET Correct = '$dta[0]', wordOne = '$dta[1]' ORDER BY saveID DESC LIMIT 1" );
```

The code uploads the html form details (mail and email) properly but will not do so for the Correct and wordOne.

Comment: why are you sending an answer array? its just one, and its an ajax call, prevent default it

Comment: I don't understand your reply, could you rephrase?

Comment: what do you have an array in the first place? your inputs are just two, and where did `answerArray` come from? and what is your real intent? an ajax submit? or a normal refresh form submission?

Comment: The array is located inside the processing.js file that the page runs. The array itself contains mainly chars (currently I am trying to just add the first two entries of the array to the database and later on will work with the rest of the array). I want to add the array to the database and add to it the user submitted data (name and mail) when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: step 1: send your data to your JS context (see http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface), and then step 2: since it's a normal web page, do whatever is necessary to get the data from javascript, to your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

you must use **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** function to send an array in php:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function js_sendData() {
            var answerToSend=JSON.stringify(answerArray);
            $.post( "save.php", {'answer': answerToSend}, function( data ) {
                $( "#status" ).html( data );
            },'json');
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

then in your php:

```
$dta= json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['answer']));
```

Comment: Actualy that exact same method of sending the data as an array has worked for me in the past without the json though in that case I called the ajax function directly from the processing.js.
Just the same, I tried what you wrote and it doesnt work either, I have no idea why but the database does not receive any information besides that in the form.